# Changing from the default "test" directory for Spring Contract's contracts and base class tests

Tags: gradle, spring-cloud-contract

I have tried changing the default test directory name for base test classes as follows:

Old:

```
bignibou-server/src/test/java/com/bignibou/signup
```

New:

```
bignibou-server/src/contracts/java/com/bignibou/signup
```

Here is the directory where my contracts live:

New:

```
bignibou-server/src/contracts/resources/contracts/signup
```

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
contracts {
    packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.bignibou'
    baseClassMappings {
        baseClassMapping(".*signup*.", "com.bignibou.signup.SignupBase")
    }
}
```

I use the same gradle configuration both for **contracts tests & integration tests**. See:

```
sourceSets {

    integrationTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java', 'src/contracts/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/it/resources', 'src/contracts/resources']
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}
```

However, since I moved my base class tests & contracts from the `test` directory, the contracts tests are nor run...

**edit**:

After searching the documentation, I found the `contractsDslDir` property that can be used as follows:

```
contracts {
    packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.bignibou'
    contractsDslDir = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/contracts/resources/contracts")
    baseClassMappings {
        baseClassMapping(".*signup*.", "com.bignibou.signup.SignupBase")
    }
}
```

However, the tests are still not run... What else I am missing?

Here is how I try to run the tests:

```
./gradlew clean check
```

**edit 2**:

I was able to get Spring Cloud Contract to find my contract using the following value for `contractsDslDir`:

```
contractsDslDir = new File("./src/contracts/resources/contracts")
```

Now the issue is that my test won't find the test base:

```
> Task :bignibou-server:compileTestJava FAILED
/Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-server/build/generated-test-sources/contracts/com/bignibou/SignupTest.java:3: error: package com.bignibou.signup does not exist
import com.bignibou.signup.SignupBase;
                          ^
/Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-server/build/generated-test-sources/contracts/com/bignibou/SignupTest.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public class SignupTest extends SignupBase {
                                ^
  symbol: class SignupBase
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**edit 3**: It is odd: Spring Cloud Contracts still seems bound to the `test` gradle task (as opposed to my custom `integrationTest` one)...

When I run `./gradlew clean integrationTest` the contracts are not even searched... However when I run `./gradlew clean test` I get the above error indicating that Spring Cloud Contract is looking for a base class but not finding one.

How can I tell Spring Cloud Contract to bind to my custom `integrationTest` gradle task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported at the moment. Feel free to find the issue or create a new one if you can't find it

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I have opened an issue as suggested: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/1158